# Gatling plugin Errors

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, gatling, scala-gatling

I have the example from https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo
It works for me everything is fine but if I try to add my own simulation or change the simulation from the example I get

Update:

just removed my own simulation and now it doesn't work haven't a clue.

```
error while starting up loggers
akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due to [akka.ConfigurationException: configuration problem while creating [akka://GatlingSystem/system/log1-Slf4jLogger] with dispatcher [akka.actor.default-d
ispatcher] and mailbox [akka.actor.default-mailbox]]
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:114)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:113)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
        at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:113)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:728)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1174)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:727)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.startDefaultLoggers(Logging.scala:108)
        at akka.event.EventStream.startDefaultLoggers(EventStream.scala:26)
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.init(ActorRefProvider.scala:622)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:53)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: configuration problem while creating [akka://GatlingSystem/system/log1-Slf4jLogger] with dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox [akka.actor.default-mailbox]
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:722)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:207)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:42)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.systemActorOf(ActorSystem.scala:550)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.akka$event$LoggingBus$$addLogger(Logging.scala:174)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Logging.scala:112)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Logging.scala:111)
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:236)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:236)
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:111)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type akka.event.LoggerMessageQueueSemantics not present
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)
        at akka.util.Reflect$.rec$1(Reflect.scala:124)
        at akka.util.Reflect$.findMarker(Reflect.scala:134)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.getRequiredType(Mailboxes.scala:90)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.getMailboxType(Mailboxes.scala:158)
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:717)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.LoggerMessageQueueSemantics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
        ... 49 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Could not start logger due to [akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due to [akka.ConfigurationException: configuration problem while creating [akka://Gatli
ngSystem/system/log1-Slf4jLogger] with dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox [akka.actor.default-mailbox]]]
        at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.startDefaultLoggers(Logging.scala:142)
        at akka.event.EventStream.startDefaultLoggers(EventStream.scala:26)
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.init(ActorRefProvider.scala:622)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:53)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
        ... 6 more
```

and if I delete my simulations in works again not sure as to what is going on but this seems very buggy I would like to use gatling but if the errors keep coming I'll be willing to hear suggestion for more user friendly plugins I need to be able to test with concurrent users and find how long the loading takes preferably something in java.

```
================================================================================
2018-07-06 08:30:49                                           5s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=2      KO=0     )
> request_1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Scenario Name -------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2018-07-06 08:30:54                                          10s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3      KO=0     )
> request_1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_2                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Scenario Name -------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2018-07-06 08:30:59                                          15s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=6      KO=0     )
> request_1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_2                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_3                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Scenario Name -------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2018-07-06 08:31:04                                          20s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=10     KO=0     )
> request_1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_2                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_3                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_5                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_6                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_7                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_8                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Scenario Name -------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2018-07-06 08:31:09                                          25s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=11     KO=0     )
> request_1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_2                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_3                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_5                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_6                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_7                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_8                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_9                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Scenario Name -------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2018-07-06 08:31:09                                          25s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=13     KO=0     )
> request_1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_2                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_3                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_4 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_5                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_6                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_7                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_8                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_9                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_10                                               (OK=1      KO=0     )
> request_10 Redirect 1                                    (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Scenario Name -------------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done:1
================================================================================

Simulation loadtests.BasicSimulation completed in 24 seconds
Parsing log file(s)...
Parsing log file(s) done
Generating reports...

================================================================================
---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
> request count                                         13 (OK=13     KO=0     )
> min response time                                    113 (OK=113    KO=-     )
> max response time                                    234 (OK=234    KO=-     )
> mean response time                                   143 (OK=143    KO=-     )
> std deviation                                         49 (OK=49     KO=-     )
> response time 50th percentile                        117 (OK=117    KO=-     )
> response time 75th percentile                        118 (OK=118    KO=-     )
> response time 95th percentile                        233 (OK=233    KO=-     )
> response time 99th percentile                        234 (OK=234    KO=-     )
> mean requests/sec                                   0.52 (OK=0.52   KO=-     )
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
> t < 800 ms                                            13 (100%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   0 (  0%)
> t > 1200 ms                                            0 (  0%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
================================================================================
```

Comment: Could you add that simulation to your question? If it causes problems than something has to be wrong there.

Comment: have you added all the required jars in pom file that are needed in your simulation

Comment: I had to use a different import than one of the ones I was using it was causing conflicts with a different import don't remember which one though